# MDX counting profit diff between years in %

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, mdx

I have data about profits etc. and I want to count % increase/decrease from previous years (if there is one) for each year. Is there a better way to do that, than just do a specific calculated member for each year? My time dimension is server generated.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a more generic calculated member that could work for Year and other levels on the time dimension.

You could use the Parallel Period mdx function to obtain the information for the previous sales. Then you can compare that to the current to get the percentage change.